# Fazer Download e abrir arquivos compactados

Tags: c#

Pessoal tenho o seguinte código em uma página aspx que compacta arquivos e depois faz um download deles...

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                JuntarArquivosAprovados(startPath);

                CompactarArquivos();

                DeletarConteudoPasta();

                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(zipPath);

                System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;

                response.ClearContent();
                response.Clear();

                response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name + ";");
                response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
                response.Flush();
                response.Close();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }


        }
```

Ele faz o download dos arquivos compactados certinho...mas quando eu vou abrir recebo a mensagem que os arquivos estão danificados e não abre...tenho um outro projeto que usa o MESMO código num WebService (asmx) e eu consigo abrir esses arquivos tranquilo...Alguém tem ideia do porque disso ?

Comment: E se mandar compactar só e tentar abrir o arquivo no servidor mesmo, ele abre normal?

Comment: abre normal sim